# Data not passing into flask/jinja template from sql database

Tags: python, html, mysql, templates, flask

So, here is my code, the html page renders, but without the database, it's just the links and image...kinda stuck.  The database already exists, i just want to display it.  I try to loop through the database in the template, but nothing shows up.

### `main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://baseball:baseball@localhost:8889/baseball'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class starting_pitchers(db.Model):

    Name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    CFIP = db.Column(db.Integer)
    xFIP = db.Column(db.Float)
    FIP = db.Column(db.Float)
    KperBB = db.Column(db.Float)
    Total_Ks = db.Column(db.Integer)
    WHIP = db.Column(db.Float)
    ERA = db.Column(db.Float)
    Innings_Pitched = db.Column(db.Float)
    Wins = db.Column(db.Integer)
    Quality_Start_Rate = db.Column(db.Integer)
    '''Swg_Strike_Rate = db.Column(db.Float)'''
    Ground_Ball_Rate = db.Column(db.Float)
    Soft_Contact_Rate = db.Column(db.Float)
    FP_Rank = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)
    SW_Rank = db.Column(db.Integer)
    CT_Rank = db.Column(db.Integer)
    HC_Rank = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, ID, Name):
        self.Name = Name
        self.ID = ID


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    baseball = starting_pitchers.query.all()

    return render_template('index.html', title="Baseball", baseball=baseball)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

---

So, that is the main python file...i realize this part is unnecessary, but stackoverflow is forcing me to type more non-code to submit this question, so...

AND

### `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Baseball01</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    </head>

<body>
<h1>Fantasy Pitcher Quick Info</h1>

<img src="C:\Users\Kristen%20Tuomey\Pictures\Saved%20Pictures\kershaw.jpg" width="400" height="300">

<p><h2> 2017</h2></p>

<h4><a href=http://www.brooksbaseball.net/pfxVB/pfx.php>PITCHf/x-Brooks Baseball</a></h4>

<p>  Used to view a particular pitcher's performance in a particular game.  Select the date, then the game, then the pitcher.  Very useful for judging recent results against prior results and gauging the reason for any changes.  For example, has this pitcher's velocity gone up or down?  Which pitch is most effective, and how often is he throwing it?</p>

<h4><a href=http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=2022356>CFIP-Baseball Prospectus</a></h4>

<p>  Predictive, rather than descriptive, global pitching statistic</p>

<h4>  <a href=http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&lg=all&qual=0&type=1&season=2017&month=0&season1=2017&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=p2017-05-08&sort=19,d>ERA minus FIP</a></h4>

<p>  ERA minus FIP is the expected regression a pitcher is likely to undergo.  A larger number generally forecasts greater positive regression, and a negative number indicates negative expected regression.</p>

<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    {% for row in starting_pitchers %}
        <tr>
        {% for d in row %}
            <td>{{ d }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the list of `Model`s in to your template with the keyword argument `baseball`. However, in your template, you are trying to reference it by the name `starting_pitchers`.

I think what are are intending to do is more like the following:

```
{% for row in baseball %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.ID }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.CFIP }}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Since the `starting_pitchers` type is not iterable, we remove the inner `for` loop and reference the properties directly by name inside the `td` tags.

Comment: File "C:\Users\Kristen Tuomey\lc101\baseball-project\templates\index.html", line 32, in top-level template code

    {% for d in row %}

    TypeError: 'starting_pitchers' object is not iterable

Comment: any help is very appreciated

Comment: Thanks...you're a saint

Comment: Any idea how to pass the column titles into the template and make them sortable?  the documentation is not there, and not much about this specific issue on here